# NUnit Get outcomes not run

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have a simple NUnit code not working, shown below:

```
[TestFixture("abc", "xyz", typeof(int))]
    public class GenericTestFixture<T>
    {
        T tt;
        string aa;
        string bb;
        public GenericTestFixture(string a, string b, T t)
        {
            tt = t;
            aa = a;
            bb = b;
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"aa is {aa}, bb is {bb}, t is {typeof(T).ToString()}");
        }


        [TestCase(1)]
        public void TestMethod(int c)
        {
            Assert.Equals(c, 1);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, after clicking the run button from test explorer, I got Outcomes with 2 Not Run message, then I put a breakpoint inside the constructor and tried debugging, but it didn't stop as expected. What is the reason and how to fix it? My NUnit version is 3.12.0 and NUnit3TestAdapter version is 3.15.1

> UPDATE1

I went to the output window and get the below log message:

```
[11/5/2019 8:21:40.468 PM Informational]    Skipping assembly - no matching test cases found
[11/5/2019 8:21:40.743 PM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.15.1.0: Test execution complete
[11/5/2019 8:21:40.815 PM Warning] No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=DataDrivenTests.GenericTestFixture.Test1|FullyQualifiedName=DataDrivenTests.GenericTestFixture.TestMethod` in D:\code\NUnit_practice\nunit-csharp-samples\DataDrivenTests\bin\Debug\DataDriven.Tests.dll
[11/5/2019 8:21:42.752 PM Informational] ========== Run finished: 0 tests run (0:00:06.1448651) ==========
```

Comment: In Visual Studio's "Output" window, change the "Show output from" drop-down to "Tests". This will show you the console output from the test run and will probably include some error message(s) from the NUnit3TestAdapter. If so, please add them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow [NUnit Generic Test Fixtures](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute#generic-test-fixtures) doc, like this:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(int), "abc", "xyz")]
public class GenericTestFixture<T>
{
    private readonly string _aa;
    private readonly string _bb;


    public GenericTestFixture(string a, string b)
    {
        _aa = a;
        _bb = b;
    }


    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"aa is {_aa}, bb is {_bb}, t is {typeof(T)}");
    }


    [TestCase(1)]
    public void TestMethod(int c)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(c, 1);
    }
}
```

Debug output:

[image: debug output]

Comment: Thanks, the above code works, but if I put typeof(int) after "xyz", then it doesn't work again with the same log message from my update. What is the reason?

Comment: According to the documentation, the type must be specified in the leading param or the named parameter *TypeArgs=new Type[] { typeof(int) }*.